# Display generated data with jquery from table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a card generate when a user want search people

```
 $("#userLst").append(
"<div class='card text-white bg-secondary mb-3' style='width: 18rem;'>"+
"<div id='idCard'class='card-body'>"+
"<input type='hidden' value='"+IdEtudiant+"'>"+
"<p class='card-title'  id='1' name='"+NomEtudiant+"'>"+NomEtudiant+"</p>"+
"<p class='card-text' name='"+PrenomEtudiant+"'>"+PrenomEtudiant+"</p>"+
"<p class='card-text' name='"+NumEtudiant+"'>"+NumEtudiant+"</p>"+
"<p class='card-text' name='"+AnneeEtudiant+"'>"+AnneeEtudiant+"</p>"+
"<input type='text' id='inptTime' class=' mt-auto' size='10'>"+
"</br>"+
"<button class='btn btn-success' onclick='Onclicked()'id='btnsendlst'>Valider</button>"+
"</div>"+
"</div>"
```

And when the user click on the button , i would like this data in card go in a table. 
i tried this but it's not working

```
function Onclicked(){
 var spans= $( "p" ).each(function(){
 $("p").attr('name');
 })
 $('#lstView').append("<tr>"+spans+"</tr>");}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe it can help you

```
function Onclicked() {
  var elem = document.getElementByTagName("p");

  for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
    var spans = elem[i].getAttribute('name');
    $('#lstView').append("<tr><td>"+spans+"</td></tr>");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer but there this a problem with  .append("<tr>"+spans+"</tr>");  nothing appear on the page. 
If I replace the "+" with "," it dislplay but outise the <tr> tag

Comment: i'm sorry where the element with attribute ID lstView? where do you want append the value of tag p?

Comment: in the same page , in a table  who have lstView ID. I just create a tag <table> in my page

Comment: can you share the table code? or try my code with <td>